# Can prolonged use of the GPS cause adverse affects?

Tags: gps, geolocation

What happens when the GPS runs continuously (more than 5 hours) in an Android device? Can it cause the battery or GPS receiver to overheat? Will it be able to keep determining my location correctly the entire time?

Comment: Unless you have your phone hooked up to a car battery, your phone will run out of charge.

Comment: If you turn on GPS, Android will use it every once in a while to get a position. If you use an app that will request a GPS location continuously then the only thing that will probably happen is that you run out of battery soon. Heating should not be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Mainly there should not be any hardware problems if the unit was tested correctly.

For other information you [can use this application that has also power monitoring for GPS](http://gigaom.com/mobile/android-power-consumption-app/).